# Calling JS Function when The tag contains duplicate 'ID' attributes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to call a JS function so i can get jquery calendar when i click on text box but it is showing error. 
I want to know how i can use both attributes for txtExpiry and for datapicker? or is there any other way ?

here is code of my text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiray"  runat="server" ID="datepicker" ClientIDMode="Static"  Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
```

here is my Function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
         $(function () {
             $('#datepicker').datepicker();
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use duplicate ID attributes - or even duplicate attributes for that matter (ID attributes should be unique for the page).

You can do this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiray"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"  Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>

<script type='text/javascript'>
         $(function () {
             $('#txtExpiray').datepicker();
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the datepicker on all jQuery selector you want...

For example :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiray"  runat="server" js='datepicker' ClientIDMode="Static"  Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
```

And in JS

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $(function () {
         $('[js="datepicker"]').datepicker();
     });
</script>
```

So you can use class, or any attribute you want.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want to make a w3c site, you must use only allowed attributes... My example ("js") is just to explain!